# Convert greyscale image to colored RGBA

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a background image, and a greyscale image, both in PNG format. I want to convert the grayscale image so that white becomes a different arbitrary color, and the "blackness" of each pixel becomes like an alpha/transparency channel. Then I want to lay it on top of the background image.

I have the following code:

```py
from PIL import Image

# load images
image = Image.open("image.png")
mask = Image.open("mask.png")

# stretch mask to fit image
mask = mask.resize(image.size)

# get the color of a pixel in the middle of the image to use as mask color
color = image.getpixel((500, 500))

# colorize the greyscale mask to that color, with the "blackness" of each pixel becoming the alpha channel
greyscale_to_color_with_alpha(mask, color)

# apply mask on top of image
image.paste(mask)

def greyscale_to_color_with_alpha(image, color):
    raise NotImplementedError
```

PIL is tagged because that's what I use currently, but answers using other image libraries are also welcome.

Comment: Maybe you could share your images and give some idea what result you are hoping for.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The greyscale image looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/wtuNN6I.jpg and the background image can be any image.